# Android - How to track the memory usage of an any running app on device programmatically?

Tags: android, memory

How to check that how much memory(RAM) is getting consumed by any of currently running app on device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html).

`getRunningAppProcesses` will get you a list of PIDs, and then `getProcessMemoryInfo` will give you memory details about them.

See the following thread for an complete, in-depth answer:  [How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813).