# How to find out memory usage of the current running application in android?

Tags: android, memory

I am working on memory usage for application. I have many applications running in my device.I am able to get the available memory using getMemoryInfo().

My problem is , i want each and every application memory consumption/usage.

e.x. I have four application running,

1) abc
2) def
3) ghi
4) klm

Now i want memory usage/consumption of each and every running above applications.

please help me out to find the individual application memory consumption and its allocation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963828/1265724)

Comment: You can go through this as well:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) is a good article that talks about memory profiling tools that can help you analyze your application's memory usages.