# How to get actual RAM usage of app in android?

Tags: java, android, ram, android-memory, java-memory-model

Quite simply, how can I get the amount of memory (in MB) that my android app is *currently* using? This would need to be done in Java so I can display this information to the user.

I've looked at other stackoverflow posts but none give a simple or accurate answer to this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-do-i-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813

Comment: Try to use the ActivityManager: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android

Comment: Please define, in technical terms, what "actual RAM usage" means. [Quoting one of the core Android engineers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2299813/115145): "Note that memory usage on modern operating systems like Linux is an extremely complicated and difficult to understand area. In fact the chances of you actually correctly interpreting whatever numbers you get is extremely low".

Comment: ActivityManager and the approach given above only give the total memory, and memory available. They given no indication as to how much memory the app itself is consuming of the RAM.

Answer (score 2):

`adb shell dumpsys meminfo packagename`

Try to execute this command with Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActivityManager` for that purpose.

It's answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963402/android-how-to-track-the-memory-usage-of-an-any-running-app-on-device-programm).

Comment: ActivityManager gives total memory and memory available. That is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for how much memory the app itself is using at a particular time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code if a performance is not critical:

```
Debug.MemoryInfo memInfo = new Debug.MemoryInfo();
Debug.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
long res = memInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) 
    res += memInfo.getTotalPrivateClean(); 

return res * 1024L;
```

If performance is critical [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666544/3415353)

Answer (score 0):

### 1. dumpsys meminfo PKG_NAME

```
...
App Summary
                      Pss(KB)
                       ------
          Java Heap:    42868  <--
        Native Heap:    52268  <--
               Code:    23608
              Stack:       96
           Graphics:     5084
      Private Other:     5620
             System:    14900

              TOTAL:   144444  <--    TOTAL SWAP PSS:      130
```

### 2. in java code

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Debug.java#640
// this is the value source of `dumpsys meminfo`.

```java
  Debug.MemoryInfo memInfo = new Debug.MemoryInfo();
  Debug.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);

  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    String javaMem = memInfo.getMemoryStat("summary.java-heap");
    String natiMem = memInfo.getMemoryStat("summary.native-heap");
    String totalMem = memInfo.getMemoryStat("summary.total-pss");

    //msg2 += "\n" + String.format("%s %s %s", javaMem, natiMem, totalMem);
    msg2 += "\n\n"+String.format("java %8s\nnati %8s\ntotal %8s",
        formatMB(Integer.parseInt(javaMem)), formatMB(Integer.parseInt(natiMem)), formatMB(Integer.parseInt(totalMem))
    );
  }

  ...

  String formatMB(double KB){
    return String.format("%.1f MB", KB/1024);
  }
```

The other api need lots of calculate,
// you can read them in Debug.java src file.
This is the closest to `dumpsys meminfo` or `android studio monitor`.