# How to get the RAM usage of an other app Android?

Tags: android, ram

I want to retrieve the ram usage of an other app and display it in my app. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the memory info using

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
```

and for a particular process use

```
activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(new int[]{process_ids});
```

which returns an array of memory information

getRunningAppProcesses will get you a list of PIDs, and then getProcessMemoryInfo will give you memory details about them.

> sources : 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/13244684/6380895
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963828/6380895
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html

Answer (score 1):

```
MemoryInfo memory_info = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
double availableMegs = memory_info.availMem / 0x100000L;

//Percentage can be calculated for API 16+
double percentAvail = memory_info.availMem / (double)memory_info.totalMem * 100.0;
```

This will give you memory usage in percentage.

Comment: You want memory usage of particular app ? for example - Facebook.